# Formatting Print Line to Single Line - Python

Tags: python-3.x, printing, format, output

Just looking for a little help on this problem, I can't seem to get the output quite right and would greatly appreciate any help someone can offer. Thank you!

So here is a part of the code that I am working with:

```
NewList = []

with open("LOCS.txt") as infile:

for line in infile:
    ThisLine = line
    NewLine = "V_ARTICLE_FULL.ISI_LOC= " + "'" + ThisLine + "'" + " OR "
    NewList.append(NewLine)
    print NewLine

for ele in NewList:
    f.write(ele)
```

The output I am getting looks like this:

' OR V_ARTICLE_FULL.ISI_LOC= '00017664
' OR V_ARTICLE_FULL.ISI_LOC= '00018373

And I would like it to look more like this:

V_ARTICLE_FULL.ISI_LOC= '00017664' OR V_ARTICLE_FULL.ISI_LOC= '00018373'

Comment: Try adding rstrip: ThisLine = line.rstrip('\n')

Comment: Yes, that did just the trick! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I posted this as the answer so you can accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my original comment, what you want to do is strip the newline from the end of the line like so:

```
ThisLine = line.rstrip('\n')
```

This will get your output to display properly.